# Net.Mail multiple recipients

Tags: c#, email

I use the `DataReader` for populate my List email and send alert email on multiple recipients and the return is correct :

```
using (OdbcDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            list.Add(reader["Email"].ToString());
            listAdd = String.Join(", ", list.ToArray());

            Response.Write(listAdd.ToString() + "<br />");
        }
    }
}
```

But if try send the alert email :

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(listAdd))
{
    foreach (var address in listAdd.Split(','))
    {
        mailMessagePlainText.To.Add(new MailAddress(address.Trim(), ""));               
    }
}
```

I have this error :

> The message header contains an invalid character: ''.

I have checked each single email address but I don't have any invalid characters. How do I resolve this?

Please help me, thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Try to put `address.Trim()` in a string and see its contents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's finding invalid character "
You might want to use:

```
address.Trim('\"') or address.Trim('\0022')
```

Though I would probably recommend cleaning the data from the data source.

I'm actually wondering why you're using the listAdd string instead of the list itself? You could use something like:

```
if (!list.Any())
{
    foreach (var address in list)
    {
        mailMessagePlainText.To.Add(new MailAddress(address.Trim(), ""));               
    }
}
```